# RC notation in IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

Is there a way to use RC notation in the IMPORTRANGE function? What I need to do is to import a certain column, which I'm finding using MATCH in the first row (headers)

`=importrange("linktosheet","sheet!c" & match(importrange("linktosheet","sheet!1:1"),"headername") )` <- which would return the n-th column

I tried to use CHAR to get the column letter from the MATCH value, but it means I have to repeat the MATCH function twice; plus, it works up to column Z; I would need to add another function to do two-letter columns.

Another way would be to use hlookup or something, but I'm afraid that would be very inefficient.

Comment: Welcome! What about [**OFFSET() function**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en#null) with `offset_rows = 0`, `offset_columns = your match() result` and `width = 1`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `let()` to avoid repeating `importrange()`, `chooserows()` to get the headers, and `filter()` to get just the column(s) where the header matches `headerName`, like this:

```
=let( 
  data, importrange("linktosheet", "sheet!A1:ZZZ"), 
  headers, chooserows(data, 1), 
  filter(data, headers = "headername") 
)
```